# DateTime.TryParseExact() is returning mixed results

Tags: c#, datetime, tryparse

I'm trying to parse a huge file that contains some lines that are DateTime.
For some reason DateTime.TryParseExact is only returning true on some of of the lines and not others.
My DateParse.txt file looks something like this:

> 2015-02-27 01:01:30
>    2015-02-27 01:01:43
>    2015-02-27 01:01:53
>    2015-02-27 01:02:05
>    2015-02-27 01:02:15
>    2015-02-27 01:02:36
>    2015-02-27 01:02:51
>    2015-02-27 01:03:04
>    2015-02-27 01:03:21
>    2015-02-27 01:03:36
>    2015-02-27 01:03:46
>    2015-02-27 01:04:01
>    2015-02-27 01:04:13
>    2015-02-27 01:04:29
>    2015-02-27 01:04:40

```
string line;  
DateTime DateTime;  
    using (StreamReader Date = new StreamReader("C:\\DateParse.txt")  
        while((line = Date.ReadLine()) != null)  
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(line, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out DateTime))  
                Console.WriteLine("True");  
            else  
                Console.WriteLine("False");
```

My output is:

> False
>   False
>   False
>   False
>   True
>   True
>   True
>   True
>   And the rest are false...

Any help in figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Trim extra space or newline character for each `line` ?

Comment: Try `line.Trim()` to remove extra space

Comment: Your format string is broken - you've got `mm` instead of `MM`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Yes it should - if you've got two values for `mm` and they're different, that will fail to parse.

Comment: @JonSkeet Just realized :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [`MM` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MM_Specifier) for months and [`mm` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#mmSpecifier) for minutes.

In your case, *only* if your string have the same minute and month value it will be parsed.

That's why only these values parsed successfully.

```
2015-02-27 01:02:05
2015-02-27 01:02:15
2015-02-27 01:02:36
2015-02-27 01:02:51
```

By the way, when I mean successfully, that doesn't mean it returns the right `DateTime` value. Since you didn't mentioned any month part with `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss` format, your `DateTime`'s month part will `1` by default. That's why after parsing operation their `DateTime` values will be;

```
2015-01-27 01:02:05
2015-01-27 01:02:15
2015-01-27 01:02:36
2015-01-27 01:02:51
```

which is wrong values based on your strings.

In your case, right format should be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

Answer (score 3):

Change this line and check

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(line, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out DateTime))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using (StreamReader Date = new StreamReader("C:\\DateParse.txt")  
        while((line = Date.ReadLine()) != null)  
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(line.Trim(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out DateTime))  
                Console.WriteLine("True");  
            else  
                Console.WriteLine("False");
```

use `line.Trim()` and `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` where `MM` for month representation and `mm` for minutes

Answer (score 0):

Just Change the mm mont to MM

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(line, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out DateTime)
```

It 'll work